# total of male and female in every year level and then all using codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have a problem about the total of male and female every year level and total of all male and female. For example I have 4 students, in grade 7(year level) I have a one female and one male student, in grade 8 I have a male student and in the grade 8 I have one male student but the problem it also count in opposite Sex. Also I have the problem in ORDER BY ASC or DESC and I don't know why.

Here is the picture->[image: total students]

Here is my modal:

```html
  function gendercountz(){
  
        $query = $this->db->query('select Sex
     , COUNT( case when Sex = "Male"
                 then 1 else 0 end ) as male
     , COUNT( case when Sex = "Female"
                 then 1 else 0 end ) as female
  from studentinformation');
            return $query->result();
        
    }
   function gendercountzx(){
      
        $querys = $this->db->query('SELECT Yearlevel, COUNT(*) AS studentcount, COUNT(case when Sex = "Male" then 1 else 0 end) AS malecount, COUNT(case when Sex = "Female" then 1 else 0 end) AS femalecount FROM studentinformation GROUP BY Yearlevel ORDER BY Yearlevel DESC');
            return $querys->result();
        
    }
```

here is my view:

```html
<table class=" table table-hover ">
            
               
           <thead>
                             <tr>
                             
                                 <th class="text-center">Year Level</th>
                                   <th class="text-center">Male</th>
                                   <th class="text-center">Female</th>
                                   <th class="text-center">Total</th>
                                  
                                   
                           </tr>
                          
                             <?php 
    foreach ($this->model_adminlogin->gendercountzx() as $ewa){ ?>
                           <tr>
                  
                   
             
                
               <td >   <h5 class="text-center"> <?php echo $ewa->Yearlevel?></h5>
   
   
     </td>
                   <td class="text-center"><?php echo $ewa->malecount?></td>
                              <td class="text-center"><?php echo $ewa->femalecount?></td>
                  
                   <td class="text-center"><?php echo $ewa->studentcount?></td>
                   
                        
                             
         </tr>
        
        <?php 
     }
    ?>  
                
    
   
         <tr>
                       
             <td class="text-center"><b>Total</b></td>
                <?php 
    foreach ($this->model_adminlogin->gendercountz() as $ewa){ ?>
                <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $ewa->male?></td>
                 <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $ewa->female?></td>
                 
                   <?php 
     }
    ?>  
                  <td class="text-center"><?php echo  $this->db->count_all('studentinformation'); ?></td>
         </tr>
                           
                           </table>
```

Comment: thank you ma'am/sir for helping me @Strawberry

Comment: why it is not ascending even I put ORDER BY ASC?

Comment: Yearlevel -> capital Y in  PHPadmin ma'am/sir

Comment: even I put Desc, 1st is Grade 11 then Grade 7. I don't know why ma'am /sir

Comment: aw sorry varchar(10) ma'am/sir

Comment: aw that's why, thank you sir/ma'am

Comment: but in what way I will use ma'am/sir

Comment: using int but I want to view also the string grade

Comment: Without seeing a proper data set (e.g an sqlfiddle) and a desired result, I don't think I can help further.

Comment: uhhm anyway still good so no probs right thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `Yearlevel` as `int` datatype...then you can use

```
function gendercountzx()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT CONCAT("Grade ", Yearlevel) as Yearlevel, COUNT(*) AS studentcount, sum(case when Sex = "Male" then 1 else 0 end) AS malecount, sum(case when Sex = "Female" then 1 else 0 end) AS femalecount FROM studentinformation GROUP BY Yearlevel ORDER BY Yearlevel DESC'); 
    return $querys->result();
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me sir @Praveen Kumar

Comment: aw click check, sorry I forgot